# Time difference between rows based on condition

Tags: sql, vertica

Not really an expert with SQL and im having problems figuring out how to do this one.

Got a table like this one:

| ID | Message | TimeStamp | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello | 2022-08-01 10:00:00 | A |
| 1 | How are you? | 2022-08-01 10:00:05 | A |
| 1 | Hello there | 2022-08-01 10:00:10 | B |
| 1 | I am okay | 2022-08-01 10:00:12 | B |
| 1 | Good to know | 2022-08-01 10:00:15 | A |
| 1 | Bye | 2022-08-01 10:00:25 | B |
| 2 | Hello | 2022-08-01 10:02:50 | A |
| 2 | Hi | 2022-08-01 10:03:50 | B |

I need to calculate the time difference each time there is a response from the B user after a message from A.

Expected result would be like this

| ID | Difference |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 60 |

Trying to use Lead function to obtain the next desired timestamp but im not getting the expected result
Any tips or advice?

Thanks

Comment: Please tag your database. Also, have you tried anything? Show us your effort. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it is already answered - it's a nice use case for Vertica's MATCH() clause. Looking for a pattern consisting of `sender = 'A'` followed by `sender = 'B'`.
You get a pattern id, and then you can group by other stuff plus the pattern id to get max timestamp and min timestamp.

Also note that I renamed both "user" and "timestamp", as they are reserved words...

```
-- your input, don't use in final query
indata(ID,Message,ts,Usr) AS (
          SELECT 1,'Hello'       ,TIMESTAMP '2022-08-01 10:00:00','A'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'How are you?',TIMESTAMP '2022-08-01 10:00:05','A'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'Hello there' ,TIMESTAMP '2022-08-01 10:00:10','B'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'I am okay'   ,TIMESTAMP '2022-08-01 10:00:12','B'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'Good to know',TIMESTAMP '2022-08-01 10:00:15','A'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'Bye'         ,TIMESTAMP '2022-08-01 10:00:25','B'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Hello'       ,TIMESTAMP '2022-08-01 10:02:50','A'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Hi'          ,TIMESTAMP '2022-08-01 10:03:50','B'
)
-- end of input, real query starts here , replace following comma with "WITH" 
,
w_match_clause AS (
  SELECT                                                                                                                                             
    *
  , event_name()
  , pattern_id()
  , match_id()
  FROM indata
  MATCH (
    PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts
    DEFINE
      sentbya AS usr='A'
    , sentbyb AS usr='B'
    PATTERN
    p AS (sentbya sentbyb)
  )
   -- ctl SELECT * FROM w_match_clause;
   -- ctl  ID |   Message    |         ts          | Usr | event_name | pattern_id | match_id 
   -- ctl ----+--------------+---------------------+-----+------------+------------+----------
   -- ctl   1 | How are you? | 2022-08-01 10:00:05 | A   | sentbya    |          1 |        1
   -- ctl   1 | Hello there  | 2022-08-01 10:00:10 | B   | sentbyb    |          1 |        2
   -- ctl   1 | Good to know | 2022-08-01 10:00:15 | A   | sentbya    |          2 |        1
   -- ctl   1 | Bye          | 2022-08-01 10:00:25 | B   | sentbyb    |          2 |        2
   -- ctl   2 | Hello        | 2022-08-01 10:02:50 | A   | sentbya    |          1 |        1
   -- ctl   2 | Hi           | 2022-08-01 10:03:50 | B   | sentbyb    |          1 |        2
)
SELECT
  id
, MAX(ts) - MIN(ts) AS difference
FROM w_match_clause
GROUP BY
  id
, pattern_id
ORDER BY
  id;
-- out  id | difference 
-- out ----+------------
-- out   1 | 00:00:05
-- out   1 | 00:00:10
-- out   2 | 00:01
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is very helpful since i didnt know about this function

Answer (score 0):

With mySQL 8.0:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, user, timestamp, ( LEAD(user) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) ) AS to_user, 
        TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(LEAD(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp), timestamp)) AS time_diff
    FROM msg_tab
)
SELECT id, time_diff
FROM cte
WHERE user='A' AND to_user IN ('B', NULL)
```